# Checking if URL has been tampered with

Tags: php

I am trying to ensure the parameter from a GET method of page 2 (which displays the result) will not be changed by others in the URL (the variables behind the question mark) by making sure users clicked the submit button on page 1 (which contains the form).

The professor ask us to use `isset()` to implement this requirement

Here's the login page: (page1.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional   ...> <html
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head>   <title>Login
 Page</title> </head>

 <body>
```

```
     <label>User ID:</label>
     <input type="text" name="uid">
     <br />
     <input type="submit" value="SubmitCredentials" name="SubmitCredentials"/>
      <br />
     </form> </body> </html>
```

And this is the second page: (page2.php)

```
<?php
    // get the data from the form
    $uid = $_GET['uid'];

    if(!isset($_GET['SubmitCredentials'])){
        include('error.html');
        exit(); 
      }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional
    ...>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>HELLO</title>
</head>
<body>
        <label>Hello,</label>
        <span><?php echo $uid; ?></span><br />

</body>
</html>
```

However, the `if` statement doesn't seem to be working. It's supposed to forward the page to `error.html` when I change the variable `uid` in the URL (e.g. when I change the URL to `http://localhost/1/page2.php?uid=admin`) but it's not. How can I fix it?

PS: a relevant tutorial I found on google>>>
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p7.html

Comment: @minitech The form is sending data via GET

Comment: Your link will be: `http://localhost/1/page2.php?uid=admin&SubmitCredentials=SubmitCredentials` **and users can change without clicking submit** `http://localhost/1/page2.php?uid=superadmin&SubmitCredentials=SubmitCredentials`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(!isset($_GET['SubmitCredentials'])){
        header('Location: error.html');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isset is not safe on Arrays. Try comparing with the `===`operator instead:

```
if(!($_GET['SubmitCredentials'] === 'SubmitCredentials')) {
  include('error.html');
  exit(); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Page #1:

```
<form method="GET" action="...">
    <input>
    <input>
    <input>
</form>
```

Submit URL:

```
http://localhost/1/page2.php?SubmitCredentials=SubmitCredentials&uid=admin&i_like_php=yes&...
```

Comment: I don't quite get what do you mean :\

Comment: There is no <form> opening tag in your HTML